# "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" error in Procedure

Tags: delphi, procedure

I am trying to write a procedure in delphi.
This procedure gets the name of `TControl` descendent element and then try to change some properties.
But when i try to do it, Delphi gives an error like:

> E2033 Types of actual and formal var
>   parameters must be identical

Procedure:

```
procedure Change_prop(var Control: TControl;height:integer;width:integer);
begin
//......
end;
```

Usage Example : `Change_prop(Label1, 50,200);`
What can be the solution of that error..Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to remove the var in the Control parameter and make it a value parameter.  Because Delphi objects are actually implemented as reference types, you can call methods on them, change member fields etc. even if you pass them to a procedure as a value or const parameter.

Comment: What about when for example I want to call OnKeyDown event, where the "Key" parameter has "var" written...? Is there any way to call it directly like OnKeyDown(Self, VK_RETURN, ssNone)  (which throws the error in the title), or do we need to create subprocedure to be called from within OnKeyDown event, and can as such be used elsewhere....?

Comment: @Just You should not call event handlers. Let the framework do that. If you need to share code, put it in a method that you call from the event handler.

Comment: I actually used the Perform method, using WM_KEYDOWN as sender, and it seems to work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Just Not the best way to do it

Comment: THe same goes for output parameters, out or var will give this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove **var** - you don't need it to change Control's properties:

```
procedure Change_prop(Control: TControl;height:integer;width:integer);
begin
......
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

As David said, the problem's in the **var**.  That doesn't mean that you can modify the members of the TControl, it means you can *replace* the TControl with another, completely different TControl, because objects are reference types.

If you're passing an object to a **var** parameter, the variable you pass has to be declared as exactly the same type as the parameter in order to preserve type safety.  Otherwise, you could do this:

```
procedure TForm1.VarControl(var control: TControl);
begin
  control := TButton.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.Mistake;
begin
  VarControl(self.Memo1); //defined as TMemo
  Memo1.Lines.Text := 'Undefined behavior here...';
end;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as undefined behaviour in Object Pascal, it is only available to C users. `TTrouble(Pointer(Random(MaxInt))).AskFor(EXPLICIT)`

Comment: @user205376 what are you going on about?!!

Comment: @David: I think it was a joke.

Comment: Clearly I need to get out more and stop SO rep-hunting!!

Comment: @User, although Delphi has no formal concept of undefined behavior the way C and C++ do, it's still a useful term. The Delphi language doesn't say what will happen in the situation Mason demonstrated. If you're lucky, your program will crash immediately, but you might have data corruption, stack corruption, or even no errors at all. It's futile to attempt to reason any further about the expected behavior of the program; all sorts of things could happen, and they may depend on outside factors, including the OS, compiler, and library versions.

Comment: @RobKennedy - This has nothing to do with the language. Not in the way it has to do in C/++. Yes, in the example shown by Mason, the behavior of THE PROGRAM is undefined. But it is because your data is in an inconsistent state, not because of the language itself.

Comment: @FreeConsulting - Gods! It makes me so happy that the delphi LANGUAGE does not have/allow undefined behaviors!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened when we passed an [unsafe] interface to a routine, as var parameter.

Our framework had methods that received interfaces as var parameters.
The 64bit compiler did not like that:

```
procedure DoStuff(var i: ISomeInterface);  // Fix a: Remove "var"   
begin   
   // DoStuff may set the I parameter to Nil!  
end;
```

used like this:

```
var  
   [unsafe] x: ISomeInterface;     // Fix b: Remove [unsafe]   
DoStuff(x);
```

The solution was to remove the var parameter **OR** to remove the [unsafe] decorator from the variable.

There is a note about that in the [Help](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Compiler_Attributes#Weak).